# É possível pegar as mensagens do chat do meu próprio perfil no Graph API?

Tags: facebook

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um app para coletar mensagens do chat do meu próprio perfil e gostaria de saber se é possível obter essas mensagens, eu já li a documentação do Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) e algumas respostas de alguns fóruns, mas eu ainda não achei uma resposta exata para essa questão. Me desculpe pela minha pergunta, mas ainda sou iniciante nessa API.

Comment: Aqui é o SO em Português, traduza sua pergunta para a galera poder te ajudar!

Comment: Matheus você errou de idioma ou errou de site. Pergunte em Português, você esta no pt.stackoverflow ou pergunte em ingles no stackoverflow.com

Comment: Texto corrigido.